# Why phone screens have full brightness during boot time?

Tags: boot

A simple question.

Why do phone screens have to be set at full brightness during power-up? (Maybe at that time the hardware's light sensor/s is initializing?)

Why did the developer/manufacturers not set the display's brightness to a lower value to allow a better User Experience?

p.s.- this came to my mind when I was restarting my phone, multiple times while debugging my Xposed module and being terribly sorry for my eyes to be having to look at the bright display.

Comment: We can't really say why... My guess is the hardware defaults to full until the OS starts and the power management services start controlling things. This question will net purely opinion answers though, I don't think there is a definitive answer

Comment: Use a fully black bootanimation if you want to keep your eyes easy :P

Comment: @AndyYan this makes me look stupid. xD

Comment: @acejavelin given the long time we have been using mobile devices (and this thing/problem still exists), I am sure there should be a strong reason to blare my display everytime I restart...

Comment: @vijayant I assume that the "strong reason" is nobody cares. Who stares at bootanimations when you can put the phone down and grab a coffee?